Short story in which a human scientist is on an alien planet attending a music gathering and egg-shaped aliens start to reproduce by splitting in half
A human scientist is on an alien planet attending a huge music gathering.  Egg-shaped aliens start to reproduce by splitting in half. Short story ends as the observing scientist feels a headache coming on.
Please help me with the name of the short story and the author.  Possibly read in an SF mag up to 50 years ago??

Is the implication that he's about to start splitting in half?

This sort of reminds me of The Wine Has Been Left Open Too Long and the Memory Has Gone Flat by Harlan Ellison.

I have read this story sometime in the past. The observing scientist's headache is due to rhe increasingly bumptious behavior of the aliens, which culminates in them splitting in half. I think it may be by Damon Knight.
